# Guidance on Azure ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

Mode can be `Http/Https/Tcp` or `autodetect` (default according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.connectivitymode?view=azure-dotnet)

AutoDetect, when running locally perform some checks (?) and choose available and/or best (?) protocol, however, creating a new `QueueClient` or `SubscriptionClient` can take like 10 seconds.

Forcing, locally, either to Https or Tcp make it close to immediate.

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Tcp;
```

But it there a recommended guidance/policy on which one to use locally ? Does `Tcp` is more performant if available ?

Same question if job located in an Azure WebJob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AutoDetect, when running locally perform some checks (?) and choose available and/or best (?) protocol, however, creating a new QueueClient or SubscriptionClient can take like 10 seconds.

It doesn't chose the best option, but tries to go for TCP, lowering it to HTTP/S if TCP ports are blocked.

> Forcing, locally, either to Https or Tcp make it close to immediate.

Correct. In such scenario probing is disabled and either current will work if it's are open, or will fill if those are blocked.

> But it there a recommended guidance/policy on which one to use locally ? Does Tcp is more performant if available ?

TCP is better *if* your network allows those ports.

> Same question if job located in an Azure WebJob.

Environment hosting WebJobs (App Service) has the required TCP ports open.

One additional comment: it looks like you're using the old client. Unless it's an old project that for some reason cannot be converted, it's recommended to use the new [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) client.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. erhhh absolutely no restriction about the new Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus for my situation. I suspect I was stuck in habits ... now it's fixed and the SystemConnectivity.Mode (except for legacy job) become useless

Comment: Glad you could switch to the new client.